# why is it impossible to import a provider from another module without explicitly importing it in NestJs?

Tags: dependency-injection, module, nestjs

i have read the following from NestJs when learning about [Dynamic modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules), in the introduction it said:

> Modules define groups of components like providers and controllers
> that fit together as a modular part of an overall application. They
> provide an execution context, or scope, for these components. For
> example, providers defined in a module are visible to other members of
> the module without the need to export them. When a provider needs to
> be visible outside of a module, it is first exported from its host
> module, and then imported into its consuming module.

But i can just use the regular `import provider from path/to/provider` statement to import the provider and use it anywhere, even outside the module, so its not impossible like they said and the only way to do it is to import it in the imports field of the `@Module()` decorator in order to use it.

Do they mean that you cannot use dependency injection to automatically use a provider defined in another module?

The only thing i can think i will lose when i import it manually (using the import statement) is that i will lose dependency injection, so is it just ineffective communication or am i missing something?

Comment: what about circular imports? I believe there's no way to solve that issue if we only have to use the `import` statement (which is transpiled into `require()`, in the end, for CJS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, it's not impossible to just `import { SomeService } from '../path/to/some.service'`, you can absolutely do that if you want. However, if the module you're in does not import the module that initially creates `SomeService` then you cannot let Nest inject it for you. If you end up needing to use `SomeService` and its methods, you will have to create that instance yourself, rather than letting Nest inject it for you.

If `SomeService` is a simple class with no constructor, this is fine, but if it has a dependency on `SomeRepository` from your ORM, or possibly other dependencies, then when you end up calling `new SomeService()` you'll need to pass the instance of `SomeRepository` as well, which usually requires you get the database instance and get out the repository from there, and the database instance is also managed by the DI system, so you have to either stay within Nest's DI boundaries or you have to essentially re-invent the wheel on how to create your classes.

Comment: okey so basically its all about dependancy injection, they could have made that more clear or explicit instead of saying that its impossible to import it.

Comment: I don't see where we say it's impossible to import it. But if you think the docs could be more clear, you're [welcome to open a PR to update them](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com)

Comment: ```When a provider needs to be visible outside of a module, it is first exported from its host module, and then imported into its consuming module.``` this implies the impossibility of importing it in other ways, i guess its all about the context, the context of dependacy injection is ommitted which i think really helps. but i'll try contribute, thank you.

Comment: I mean, Nest is all about dependency injection in the first place, so I think it's just an assumed context that's here. But thanks for contributing as well!